# Target configuration panel on LG IDE

Tags: webos, lg, smart-tv

I'm trying to debug a TV app on LG IDE. In order to connect the real TV, I need to create a "target", that is, a real TV with an IP address. This should be done via "target configuration" on the IDE, but I can't find this panel. Does anybody know how can I activate this panel?

Answer (score 6):

"Window -> Show View -> Target Configuration"? Then I have seen in the right bottom corner.

For me it works fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't have that option on the Show View menu. The panel was visible n the IDE when I've installed, but somehow I closed it and never could find it again. In fact, I still have the target I've created the first day.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this steps:

```
Window menu > Show View > Target Configuration
```

Now you can see **Target Configuration section** at right-top.

Now **right click** to **emulator**. Select 'Connect' option.

It works. Enjoy!